# Mandelbrot set: knowing if a regular point is in the mandelbrot set

Tags: complex-numbers

Let's say we have a point on an XY coordinate plane: $A(0.2, -0.1)$
We need to find if it's located in the mandelbrot set using the equation $z'=z^2+c$ which means turning point A into a complex number.

I'm having trouble understanding the complicated symbols Wikipedia provides so I need help with turning points into complex numbers and using them in the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Your point is
$$A=\left(\frac{1}{5},-\frac{1}{10}\right).$$
We can express it as $a+ib$:
$$A=\frac{1}{10}\left(2-i\right).$$
Define the function
$$f(z):=z^2+A.$$
Your point will belong to the Mandelbrot set if the sequence
$$f(0),f(f(0)),f(f(f(0))),\ldots$$
remains bounded.

This will be the case since $|A|=\sqrt{5}/10<2$ and the disk centered at $0$ with radius $2$ belongs to the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to subtract or do anything with i. Sorry maybe I should have put that in my question.

Comment: In this case, you should read an intructory book to complex analysis before studying the Mandelbrot set. I recommend the book *Visual Complex Analysis*.

Comment: Also question. When we express it as a+ib why put a 2-i there. Does the two have anything to do with the 1/5? I would expect it to look like 1/5 + -1/10(i). Can you please explain?

Comment: I just factored the $1/10$.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll take a look at the book you told me about.